# Can't click a button with javascript using execute_script Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[image]I'm trying to get rid of cookies popup by accepting cookies and clicking confirm. I don't have any problem with clicking an input "zgadzam się na", but clicking a button "potwierdź"seems to be impossible. My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

auction_url='https://www.g2a.com/grand-theft-auto-v-rockstar-key-global-i10000000788017'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get(auction_url)

add_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="webklipper-publisher-widget-container-notification-frame"]'))
)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="webklipper- 
publisher-widget-container-notification-frame"]'))
print('ads popup detected')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="webklipper-publisher-widget- 
container-notification-close-div"]').click()
print('ads popup closed')
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#cookies-select-all').click();")#works fine
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(76) > div > div > div > div > div.modal-options__buttons > button.btn.btn-primary').click();")#error
```

The error i get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

Interestingly, when I execute this js code in browsers console, i don't get any errors

Comment: what the button you want to click if possible screenshot

Comment: could you add the html surrounding the button :)

Comment: I've added a screenshot, html is aviable at https://www.g2a.com/grand-theft-auto-v-rockstar-key-global-i10000000788017

Answer (score 4):

Try below code work fine with me:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(60) > div > div > div > div > div.modal-options__buttons > button.btn.btn-primary > span').click();")
```

OR you can with the below one for find element

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.modal-window button.btn-primary").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this website creates crazy amount of `<div class="ReactModalPortal"></div>`, and I was using div:nth-child(x), where x is this strange, non-constant number of blank divs. My x was constant so I was making wrong selection...

Here's a solution:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('modal-options__buttons')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(76) > div > div > div > div > div.modal-options__buttons > button.btn.btn-primary').click();")#error
```

Try with button click with CSS Selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.btn.btn-primary span'))).click()
```